# Is there a way to include an if statement in a variable?

Tags: php

I am trying to come up with an IF statement inside a php variable then return the variable but i am getting an error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)

```
      $output .= '<tr>  
                      <td>'.$row["case_no"].'</td>  
                      <td>'.$row["description"].'</td>  
                      <td>'.$row["claimant"]." VS ".$row["defendant"].'</td>  
                      <td>'. if($row["court_date_assigned"] == 1){ echo "result" } .'</td>
                      <td>'.$row["court_date_assigned"].'</td> 
                      <td>'.$row["court_date_assigned"].'</td> 
                      <td>'.$row["court_date_assigned"].'</td>  
                 </tr>  
                      ';  
  }  
  return $output;
```

Comment: Use ternary operator and don't miss the semicolon.

Comment: I don't see the mysql question ... You should tag properly

Comment: Should me more like this http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b4f48db4b74c0b94237f73c4e990aec87ee7fe9e

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ternary operator, and assuming you have a bool in $row['court_date_assigned'] you can use a strict match (so the type must also match). More info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

You were also mixing double and single quotes (around the 'VS').

```
$output .= '
<tr>  
  <td>'.$row['case_no'].'</td>  
  <td>'.$row['description'].'</td>  
  <td>'.$row['claimant'].' VS '.$row['defendant'].'</td>  
  <td>'.($row['court_date_assigned'] === 1 ? $result : '') .'</td>
  <td>'.$row['court_date_assigned'].'</td> 
  <td>'.$row['court_date_assigned'].'</td> 
  <td>'.$row['court_date_assigned'].'</td>  
</tr>';
```

Comment: FYI: mixing double and single quotes is no problem for php, but:
1. Single quotes are more performant
2. You're using html, so you might need double quotes and using single quotes to wrap you're strings will make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$output .= '<tr>  
                      <td>'.$row["case_no"].'</td>  
                      <td>'.$row["description"].'</td>  
                      <td>'.$row["claimant"]." VS ".$row["defendant"].'</td>  
                      <td>'. ($row["court_date_assigned"] == 1 ? "result" : "") . '</td>
                      <td>'.$row["court_date_assigned"].'</td> 
                      <td>'.$row["court_date_assigned"].'</td> 
                      <td>'.$row["court_date_assigned"].'</td>  
                 </tr>  
                      ';  
  }  
  return $output;
```

You can perform an if else like this:

```
if ( expression )
{
    echo 1;
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

into this:

```
echo ( expression ? 1 : 0 );
```

or

```
if ( expression )
{
    $x = 1;
} else {
    $x = 0;
}
```

into this:

```
$x = ( expression ? 1 : 0 );
```

Comment: For string concatenation with the ternary operator you have to wrap your ternary operator in parentheses, or else it will only set the string to the result of the ternary operator.
example: echo ' value is  '.($value===true? 'true':'false').' !'; will output 'value is true !' while echo ' value is  '.($value===true)? 'true':'false'.' !'; will output 'true'.